# Android apk decompile - can I re-sign same to allow to app replacement upon installation

Tags: android, image, launch

It's rather typical I suppose somebody asks app be developed and then publishes on Google Play. Then much time later publisher wants to make changes when having only apk file. Or somebody wants to make changes to his/her old app.

I need to change background picture of app of which I have apk only. I `apktool` then `java -jar signapk.jar certificate.pem key.pk8` as I've found.

However upon installation it gives error `same name conflicting signature`. Can I keep signature when changing apk? Can virtuous-ten-studio or other app do that?

Added: how can I see key info (like name etc.) from apk? is it appropriate to put apk on Google Play signed with old certificate.pem key.pk8?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this.  You need the original signing key used to sign the app.

Comment: You need the original signing key used to sign the app.  There is no way around this.

Comment: my added concern is about Google Play with apk signed with standard old key, is it safe?

Comment: What do you mean, "is it safe"?

Comment: like does not break any rules

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. If you want to be able to update an APK in the play store, you have to sign it with the same key that was used the first time it was published.  There are no exceptions to this rule.

Comment: thank you. I learned some today about signing apk for Google Play, I signed with newly generated key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105457/discussion-between-alexei-martianov-and-doug-stevenson).